# Compact Keyboard Recommendations?

Tags: keyboard, peripherals

Any recommendations for a high-quality compact (no number pad) keyboard, preferably $50 or less?

Criteria:

- $50 or less
- Preferably with laptop-style keys (scissor switches instead of rubber
  membranes ala cheap desktop
  keyboards)
- Quiet (I'm a Model-M kind of guy, but this isn't a good environment
  for a noisy keyboard)
- Don't care too much about media keys, USB ports, etc

I like the Apple Wireless Keyboard, and have heard the Happy Hacking keyboards recommended by others, but they're both a bit outside our budget.

There have been several questions about keyboards (check the "peripherals" tag) but none about compact keyboards as far as I can tell. Nobody demands more from their keyboards than programmers, so while it's a somewhat subjective question, I figured this is the best place to ask.

Comment: May I ask why the need for compact keyboard for a programming organization?

Comment: I'm curious about that as well. A compact keyboard is the opposite of what I would want, personally.

Comment: Nice question. I've never used the numberkeypad in 10++ years. I've run into users repeatedly who ask the same thing. It clutters up the desktop bigtime. The extra keys just get in the way for high-volume touch typists.

Comment: @Uri: Lack of cursor keys and a number pad significantly reduces the distance between they keys and the mouse (for right handed users).

Comment: That makes sense, Greg. I tend not to use the mouse much (if at all) while programming, so I just never noticed it. I didn't realize it was a common issue among programmers.

Comment: Moving my hand those 30 degrees from the key to the nouse is probably the most exercise that I get in a day... Also, I like curved keyboards (MS Ergo 4000) and none of them come without this stuff, AFAIK. But I understand the issue.

Comment: Uri: Eschewing the numberpad is not entirely uncommon among programmers. This isn't an organization-wide thing, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem / software tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought the [logitech newtouch keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/3046&cl=au,en) which has a smaller footprint than a regular keyboard and it's great. Nice and quiet, no "multimedia keys" and has a nice feel. It's also great as a programming keyboard because the function keys aren't hijacked by those ridiculous "shortcuts" that are so common on other keyboards. You hit F5 and you get a build in visual studio. I bought it after buying the [ultra flat](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/177&cl=au,en) which had a good feel to it, but the key layout was just awful.

Comment: Oh, those look nice!  I wish Logitech sold them here in the US.

Comment: the newtouch is called the classic in the US... here's a link http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboards/&cl=us,en&page=1&filter=0&sort=4

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be close enough to what you are looking for:

[**BTC 6100C Silver & Black 86 Normal Keys 9 Function Keys USB Ultra Slim Multimedia Keyboard**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823110006)

- It costs $20
- It has laptop-style keys with scissor switches
- It has media keys, which doesn't sound like a negative for you
- It has five eggs on NewEgg, with 32 user reviews
- Not sure if it's quiet since I don't own one (reviews didn't seem to mention it either)

[Keyboard http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9f6982eb63.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9f6982eb63.jpg)

Comment: That looks good.  Out of stock at Newegg, but hopefully I can find it elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed, this does look good, but I can't seem to find it for sale anywhere. Does anybody know where to purchase this keyboard?

Comment: I just received a response from the company that made this keyboard, and they said they stopped making it 2 years ago. Bummer. It looks great.

Comment: I searched for it on Amazon (Dec 2014) and found this. It comes close to the BTC 6100c: [Genius LuxeMate i200](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B003YGVDDU/) I'm thinking of buying and testing it out.

Comment: Nevermind. It is not as good as the BTC keyboards: http://www.amazon.com/review/R1D2MV9XDVUBX7/ref=cm_cr_pr_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B003YGVDDU#wasThisHelpful

Answer (score 1):

**[TypeMatrix](http://www.typematrix.com)**
(Does not meet your price-requirement, but for posterity's sake)

[image: TypeMatrix keyboard from above]

- Compact
- Ergonomic
- Available in Qwerty, Dvorak and blank (also with a variety of rubber covers)
- Laptop-style keys

Answer (score 0):

What about those roll-up keyboards?  They're definitely rubber membranes, but they're also extremely quiet and extremely portable.  I'd be surprised if you can find a keyboard that fits ALL of the criteria you specified, but the roll-up keyboard at least hits all but one of them.

http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/input/5a7f/?cpg=ab

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard layout, scissor switches, and good reviews by people who have used Apple keyboards, but want Windows/Linux keyboard layout: [GMYLE (TM) Super Slim USB 2.0 Mini Keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003PHJJV6)

[image: GMYLE Super Keyboard]